# How can I get a correct decimal results for a Python modulo operation (without extra libs)?

Tags: python, math, modulo

I am trying to get a correct decimal (not scientific) expression for the following equation. It seems, by default, Python prints the scientific notation. I am using Python on an embedded system, so I cannot easily install libs. I am looking for a default way to get the correct result.

```
>>> 4292739359**(-1) % 4292739360
2.329514830439068e-10
```

The [correct expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4292739359%5E%28-1%29%20mod%204292739360) is 4292739359. Python seems to show different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python equivalent is using [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow):

```
>>> pow(4292739359, -1, 4292739360)
4292739359
```

Comment: As long as you have python 3.8 or later, not a given on an embedded system. Otherwise you'll need to write a few lines of code to implement a variant of the extended euclidean algorithm.